# Implementing Google Saved Games for Android (Java)

Tags: java, snapshot, google-drive-android-api

I'm attempting to implement a VERY simple saved games setup on Android.  I am providing two buttons to the user-- one is "save" and one is "load."

Both will call simple functions:

Save(name);
Load(name);

When I save, I want it to overwrite whatever exists, if it has the same name-- no matter what.  Similary, if I try to load, and the name doesn't exist, I just want to bomb out and say, nope, doesn't exist.

(The game has user created levels, so it would be too dangerous to sync it behind the scenes-- my users will have to do their own conflict management).

Here's my problem... two problems actually.  One, I cannot find any sample code that is simpler than a deluxe save/load suite designed for multiple save games, conflict resolution, and a cherry on top.  The second problem is, even the complex code is so full of depreciations that I can't even paste it into my code and start playing with it (even the apparently newest stuff is full of unresolvable methods and depreciations).

Can anyone either explain, or point me to, a "simplest" implementation of saved games, that just writes some data to by synced, and then reads it back?